# Value of "width= 100%" in Angular WebApp is smaller than actual browser width

Tags: html, css, angular

I am working on an Angular App and currently encountering a problem where the maximum width of my Angular application is smaller than it should be and I do not understand why. I can only show some of the code for several reasons but I will try my best to include crucial parts.

This all started when I added a `display: flex` to my application since I wanted to have sticky footer and header while the body content should be scrollable. In order to do this I added following content to my `styles.scss`:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 99.9%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
.content {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

And my app.component.html looks like this now:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <app-header></app-header>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

This achieved what I wanted but had the side effect that now my application has a fixed maximum width I can not seem to get around. I took a look at the dev console in Firefox and it shows me that my `html` and `body` dimensions are **1920 x Height**. However, my `app-root` only has a dimension of **1530 x Height**.

Before I added `display:flex` the width dimension worked completly fine. Am I missing something obvious right now?

Comment: _“However, my app-root only has a dimension of 1530 x Height.”_ - and what formatting gets applied to this element?

Comment: see if you're include bootstrap.css -see that bootstrap.css include mediaquerys to container- And the mediaqueries is more "specific" that a single value. You can see in this fool stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2odry3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html that your code work: tip: rename your class `container` to `custom-container`

Comment: Also, if all else fails `min-width: 100%` could be a last resort to see if any elements are restricting each other.

Comment: @Eliseo Your tip to rename to `custom-container` actually solved my problem, thanks. Can you give me an explanation on why exactly it is needed to rename it to a name other than `container`?

Comment: @hullunist, as you has import bootstrap.css you has a .css like `@media(min-width:1920px) { .container{  max-width: 1530px;    }}` you has `.container{width: 100%;}`  but the "max-width" is stronger that your width. -I'm not prety sure that if you declare `.container{max-width: 100%;}` and put your .css after import the bootstrap.css solve also your problem-

Answer (score 0):

Maybe global settings:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```